# Basement door gap - how to improve and avoid water entering basement

Tags: doors, basement, waterproofing, sealing, door-frame

Suffered a flood this weekend while we were out of town and water came in from the door (see photos). Trying to find solutions to improve the seal but am not knowledgeable in this area. Getting a new door is not an option, the door is not a standard size and this is an old house (had a company come out to take a look today). Really just trying to avoid a flood situation from happening again, had we been home we would have been able to contain it but we are set to go out of town again soon and just need peace of mind. I looked at getting quick dam expanding barrier bags for additional support but would like to figure out how to better seal the door. From the outside there is a gap were the concrete is and it is not flush to the door. A thought there is to somehow add more concrete and even another layer of bricks to add more height. From the inside there is a gap on the right side and im not sure how to seal that since the door and the frame are not flush. If anyone has any advise or can guide us in the right direction we would greatly appreciate it. The summer storms in Georgia seem to only be getting worse. :(

https://imgur.com/5d2hTty

https://imgur.com/t7I5qZX

Comment: Door sealing can be improved, but no door is waterproof.  You should look into the control of the water.

Comment: Heavy duty weather stripping will help some, but you need to find out how the water is coming in before you can fix permanently.  Was it a minor(bucketful) or major inches/feet of water flood?  Drainage and/or keeping rain away from the door would probably be in your future.

Comment: We have a drain in the drive way and a sump pump that usually do the trick but there was so much debris that it clogged the drain and the breaker flipped on the pump and it wasn't working -- a lot of bad luck at once while no one was home, unfortunately. Any tips on how to improve sealing?

Comment: Improving the seals can depend on what type the door now uses.  Since you know the series of events that led to the water building up, I would concentrate on making those things like the sump pump and drainage more failsafe.  Have the power to the sump pump checked and any less than optimal conditions rectified. Remove loose debris that can clog the drain. Examine the possibility of installing another drain or possibly diversion of any gathered water.   I can't give specific details. I don't live there.

Comment: Should find out why the breaker tripped.  A sump pump working normally does not require too much power.  Look into backup battery sump pumps, they work if the breaker trips or the power goes out in a storm.

Comment: I'd say time for a second pump. Even a door with a magnetic seal will still let water in once enough of it gets there.